# How to change to default Localization Client language to translate

Tags: 6, i18n-l10n

Localization Client allow me only to translate from English to one of others languages.

It is possible to translate from language x to English too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The reason is the way the Drupal translation system is built. Original strings (defined in modules) must be written in English. This means all translation will be from English to X-language.

Comment: Thanks, is there any module for doing that kind of job? Ex. I have a custom template for teaser. For i18n I must do if else statement for some static content in the template, it would be great if I could use t() function for this.

Answer (score 1):

The Locale module (in core) will detect your t() strings and provide an interface for translations. Handbook page explaining it in summary can be found here: [Translating a site interface to different languages (Locale core module)](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/locale).